# Dos css distintos para dos tablas en html

Tags: html, css

me estoy volviendo loco, tengo dos tablas en html y un css con el siguiente codigo

```
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

En una de las tablas tiene que ser ese estilo, pero en la otra no quiero que no tenga borde o que se blanco...

Comment: ¿Y por qué no utilizás el selector `.clase`? A una tabla le agregás la clase "clase" y a la otra no... Es un [selector de clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), por cierto.

Comment: si utilizo .clase table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
} solo me coge el borde de la tabla no de las celdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dijeron mas arriba, puedes usar una clase o un id por tabla.

#### Con clases

```html
<table class="tabla1"> </table>
<table class="tabla2"> </table>
```

```css
/* Todos los elementos que tengan la clase tabla1 */
.tabla1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Todos los elementos th que estén dentro de otros que tengan la clase tabla1 */
.tabla1 th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabla2 {
// estilos
}
```

#### Con IDs

```html
<table id="tabla1"> </table>
<table id="tabla2"> </table>
```

```css
/* El elemento que tenga id tabla1 (No debería haber dos elementos con el mismo id) */
#tabla1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Los elementos th que esten dentro de un elemento con id tabla1 */
#tabla1 th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tabla2 {
// estilos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo no usar una propiedad para toda la clase table, si vas a tener varios estilos, es decir mejor creas una clase única para cada tabla, o puedes dejar los elementos comunes, y los elementos propios en clases separadas.

El siguiente ejemplo contiene 2 tablas, las cuales cada una hace referencia a una clase que puedes personalizar en tu hoja de estilo.

```
<style type="text/css">

    .table1 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .table2 {
        border: 4px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .celda {
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:5px;
    }

</style>

<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="celda">2</td>
        <td class="celda">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celda">2</td>
        <td class="celda">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
    <table class="table2">
    <tr>
        <td class="celda">2</td>
        <td class="celda">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celda">2</td>
        <td class="celda">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Eso es correcto como hemos hablado antes, pero no me añade el borde a las filas y columnas, solo el borde exterior..y lo necesito para crear una cuadricula